# Python String Template - Using percentage delimiter

Tags: python, templates, python-2.7

I am trying to learn string Template module and facing hiccups using alternative delimiter.

`temp_text_dollar` has variable names prefixed by `$` and it works fine

```
>>> import string
>>> val = {'a1':'VAL1' , 'a2' : 'VAL2' , 'a3' : 'VAL3' , 'a4' : 'VAL4' }
>>> temp_text_dollar = string.Template(" This is a sample text ${a1} $a3 ")
>>> print temp_text_dollar.substitute(val)
 This is a sample text VAL1 VAL3
>>> print temp_text_dollar.delimiter
$
>>> print temp_text_dollar.idpattern
[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*
>>> print temp_text_dollar.template
 This is a sample text ${a1} $a3
```

`temp_text_pct`  has variable names prefixed by `%` and it doesn't work.

```
>>> temp_text_pct = string.Template(" This is a sample text %a1 %a3 ")
>>> class MyTemplate(string.Template):
...     delimiter = '%'
...     idpattern = '[a-z]*'
...
>>> t2 = MyTemplate(temp_text_pct)
>>> print t2.substitute(val)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/string.py", line 172, in substitute
    return self.pattern.sub(convert, self.template)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
>>> print t2.delimiter
%
>>> print t2.idpattern
[a-z]*
```

Looks like typo error and I am unable to crack it.

Can `string.Template` be used to replace `%` variables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created a template **from a template**:

```
>>> temp_text_amp = string.Template(" This is a sample text %a1 %a3 ")
[...]
>>> t2 = MyTemplate(temp_text_amp)
```

`temp_text_amp` *is not a string*. This is what is causing the traceback you see.

Create your template object from a string instead:

```
t2 = MyTemplate(" This is a sample text %a1 %a3 ")
```

Your next problem is that you limited your `idpattern` to *just letters*:

```
idpattern = '[a-z]*'
```

but your actual template string uses digits too.

This works just fine:

```
>>> import string
>>> class MyTemplate(string.Template):
...     delimiter = '%'
...     idpattern = '[a-z0-9]*'
... 
>>> t2 = MyTemplate(" This is a sample text %a1 %a3 ")
>>> val = {'a1':'VAL1' , 'a2' : 'VAL2' , 'a3' : 'VAL3' , 'a4' : 'VAL4' }
>>> t2.substitute(val)
' This is a sample text VAL1 VAL3 '
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn.  Didnt notice that numbers are missing in `idpattern`. But `val` had values for `a1` & `a3` keys

Comment: @Manuel: ah, I see where I made a mistake in my own session, removing that line. I initially had omitted the `*` in the pattern.